# How to setup dynamic dns server on Raspberry Pi using dnsmasq

Tags: dns

I need to setup a dynamic dns on the raspberry pi. For this I have installed the `dnsmasq` service. I have created a file with name `home.dns` and below are its contents:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.1.5,48h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
domain=home.com

dhcp-host=00:28:f8:32:44:a7,pi1
dhcp-host=b8:27:eb:5a:9f:7c,pi2
```

As I want this to work with dynamic ip address so I have not used any static ips. After restarting the service, it failed and showed error in line `dhcp-range=192.168.1.5,48h` with this message `dnsmasq: bad dhcp-range at line 3 of /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.dns`. How can I resolve this issue.

I want to setup a local dns on raspberry pi so that regardless of Ip address I can easily reach all the pi's/devices by their domain names in the network, like `pi1.home.com`. Also, if it works, do I need to disable DHCP from my router. If is there any other option available to setup a dns, please point me to correct link/instructions.

Thanks

Comment: if you need a full DNS resolver with DNSSEC, try "unbound" ("dnsmasq" is just a DNS forwarder) and good read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software

Answer (score 3):

You haven't actually specified a range.

You should choose your own range end, but 50 could be a good start, e.g.

dhcp-range=192.168.1.5,192.168.1.50,48h

See https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq

Regards, Geoff

Comment: @s-andrew, would you like to Select my Answer?